# Shared pointer polymorphic object's reference not being passed properly

Tags: oop, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I have a program whose main calls Simulation class object in the following manner.

```
int number_of_sims = std::stoi(num_sims)/MAX_THREADS_SIM_THREADS;
for (int inst=0; inst<Instruments.size(); inst++)
    {
        Simulation Simulations(Instruments[inst], Symbols[inst], number_of_sims);
        SimVector.push_back(Simulations);
    }
```

The simulation class in turn makes call to class Analysis and class Strategy and has the following skeleton.

```
class Simulation
{
public:
    Simulation();
    Simulation(Instrument& instrument, String& Symbol, int runs);
    virtual ~Simulation();
    boost::shared_ptr<Strategy> getStrategyName(String& StratName);
    bool constructTimeSeries();
    bool InitializeStrategy();
    bool getMeanMTM();
    bool printStrategyTrades(int run);
    bool printAggregateMTM();
    bool Run();
private:
    String Symbol_;
    double Mean_;
    int runs_;
    Instrument instrument_;
    std::map<String, DoubleVector> AggregateMTM_;
    boost::shared_ptr<Analysis> analysis_;
    boost::shared_ptr<Strategy> strategy_;
};
```

The constructor looks something like this.

```
Simulation::Simulation(Instrument& instrument, String& Symbol, int runs) 
: instrument_(instrument), Symbol_(Symbol), analysis_(new Analysis(instrument)), runs_(runs)
{
    String filelocation = "/else/abc/xyz/klmn/file.config";
    ConfigReader Config(filelocation, "=", false);
    Config.parseFile();
    String StrategyName = Config.getValue("strategyname");
    Logger::getLogger().log(DEBUG, "The Strategy name is: " + StrategyName);
    strategy_ = getStrategyName(StrategyName);
}
```

Now i make a polymorphic call to the XYZ strategy in the config file as below.

```
boost::shared_ptr<Strategy> Simulation::getStrategyName(String& StratName)
{
    if (StratName.compare("XYZ") == 0)
        return (boost::shared_ptr<Strategy>(new XYZ(instrument_, Symbol_)));  
}
```

My XYZ strategy class inherits the strategy base and populates the TS_(LongStruct vector) member variable which is a protected member of class Strategy and uses it to perform certain funtions, one of which is getting the size of the vector.

The skeleton of these two classes looks something like below.

```
class Strategy
{
public:
    Strategy(Instrument& instrument, String& Symbol);
    virtual ~Strategy();
    virtual bool Initialize();
    virtual bool printData(std::ofstream& outputfile);
    virtual double getMeanMTM();

protected:
    virtual int CalculateTradeSignal(double& lower_limit, double& upper_limit, double& tau, double& meanTau, bool trade);
    virtual double CalculateMTM(double& EntryPrice, double& ExitPrice);
    std::map<int, String> Side_; 
    std::vector<String> TradeVector_;
    Instrument instrument_;
    LongToSymbolInfoPairVector TS_;
    String Symbol_, start_, end_, tradeend_;
    int numticks_, tradeticks_, tickinterval_;
    double MeanMTM_;
};
```

XYZ:

```
class XYZ : public Strategy 
{
public:
    XYZ(Instrument& instrument, String& Symbol);
    virtual ~XYZ();
    bool Calculate(); 
    bool CalculateTau();
    bool Initialize();
    bool updateNetPosition(int SigVal, int i, double& tau);
    double getMeanMTM();
    bool printData(std::ofstream& outputfile);

private:
    // Initializers
    bool entry_, trade_;
    int netposition_;
    long unsigned int tauMA_, lokBK_;
    long entryT_, exitT_;
    // TODO: Move the temporary variables, entryP, exitP, MTM to local variables 
    double entryP_, exitP_, MTM_, stoploss_, takeprofit_;
    double lowtau_, hightau_;    
    LongVector entrytimeVector_, exittimeVector_;
    IntVector posVector_;
    DoubleVector entryPriceVector_, exitPriceVector_, MTMVector_, tauVector_;
};
```

In the CalculateTau function i try to get the size of the TS_ vector which has been initialized in the following manner.

```
bool XYZ::CalculateTau()
    {
        Logger::getLogger().log(DEBUG, "Calculating Tau  .. ");
        Logger::getLogger().log(DEBUG, "The size of the TS is: " + std::to_string(TS_.size()));
        return true;
    }

Strategy::Strategy(Instrument& instrument, String& Symbol) 
: instrument_(instrument)
{

}

bool Strategy::Initialize()
{
    TS_ = instrument_.GetTS();
return true;
}
```

Here get TS does the following:

```
class Instrument
{
    public:
    Instrument();
    virtual ~Instrument();
    LongToSymbolInfoPairVector GetTS() { return newTS_; }

private:
    LongToSymbolInfoPairVector TS_, newTS_;

};
```

Now the problem is that i am getting the value of this size as 0.

Kindly assist in letting me know, where am i going wrong here.

Comment: Please try to reduce your example to a [mcve](/help/mcvs) - there are tonns of uncrelated membervariables and also some code, that seems to be irrelevant to the question. Of course, at the end you still have to make sure, you example still exhibits the same error. This makes it easier for you and us to find the rootcasue of your problem and allows us to verify any answers we might come up with. Also explain, more clearly, what result you are expecting.

Comment: Also, on a superficial glance, it seems, you are not only showing too much unrelated code, but related code seems to be missing too, like where are you calling initialize or calculate tau

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get around this problem by reducing the indirection from Simulation->Analysis->Instrument to Instrument->Simulation->Analysis then Analysis->Strategy